# ContextCompat is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement permission method on one of my menu in android application but its giving me error like below

> The method checkSelfPermission(Context, String) in the type ContextCompat is not applicable for the arguments (new BottomSheetListener(){}, String)

My code for this menu is like below

```
else if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.save_image) {

    int gpermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    if (gpermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        makeRequest1();
    } else {
        saveQuote();
    }
}
```

Please check and let me know if someone can help me :)

Comment: if this code is in a Activity class, write : `YourActivity.this` instead of `this`, else get the context from the parent Activity

Comment: This is working fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this code is in a Activity class, write :

```
YourActivity.this
```

instead of `this`, else get the context from the parent Activity and use it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
int gpermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
```

write this:

```
int gpermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
```

You are referencing `BottomSheetListener` and you should reference `Context`. In the constructor of `BottomSheetListener` pass a `Context` from `Activity` or `BottomSheet` and write a function `getContext()` returning this context object.

Comment: Now I am getting error like "The method getContext() is undefined for the type new BottomSheetListener(){}"

Comment: This is correct, it may also depend on where the code that is calling ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() is being called from. In the context of an Activity the 'this' keyword should technically work.

Comment: @Rajubhai Rathod Read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: Good call missed that last line.

Comment: @Ashish Ranjan comments MyActivity.this is working fine